# Vue.Js - data not updating

Tags: vue.js

I am very new to Vue.Js so please forgive me for this newbie question. I have a `result` variable in my `data()` method, and when I try to update the `result` variable using `this.result = result`, in the browser, the original variable remains the same. I don'; know what I am doing wrong. I have googled for a few hours and found no answer. As always, any help is greatly appreciated. I don't know why my data isn't updating. here is my code;

play.js

```
    Vue.component('game', {
        template: '#game-template',

        data: function () {
            return {
                ready: null,
                result: 0
            }
        },
        props: ['gameid'],


        methods: {
            loadGame: function () {
                this.$http.get('../api/games/ready/' + this.gameid).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.body === '1') {
                        // process coinflip upon ready game
                        var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
                        this.result = result;
                        console.log(this.result);


                    }

                }.bind(this));
            }
        },

        ready: function () {
            this.loadGame();

            setInterval(function () {
                this.loadGame();
            }.bind(this), 5000);
        }
    });

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

View:

```
extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div id="app">
        <game v-bind:gameid="{{$gameid}}"></game>
    </div>

    <template id="game-template">
        <div>
            <strong>Result:</strong> @{{ result }}

        </div>
    </template>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/play.js"></script>

    @endsection
```

Comment: Check console log for errors.  Try inverting the `if (response.body === '1') ` test to see if that is the problem.

Comment: No console errors. i also changed `if (response.body === '1')` to `if (response.body === '0') and it did not do anything...

Comment: I just removed the if entirely and now it works... i guess I have to change the conditional. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  Dont forget to add an answer and mark as solved.

Comment: It's been three years Tom, time to give the man his solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1 == true //true
1 === true // false
```

I think the problem may lies in the fact that HTTP returns `true`, not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'this' keyword has different value than you expected. Try this approach:

```js
loadGame: function () {
  let self = this;
  this.$http.get('../api/games/ready/' + self.gameid).then(function (response) {
     if (response.body === '1') {
       var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
       self.result = result;
     }
   });
}
```