# Vue2 data not being updated in template after retrieving from url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I am using Vue.js version 2, trying to update a variable which is used in the view.

Bear with me, I have the following code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#products',

    data: {
       showProductModal: false,
       product: {}

    },

    methods: {

      retrieveProduct(id) {
        axios.get('/product/'+id).then(function (response) {
            this.product = response.data;
            console.log(this.product);
        });
      }
  }
```

Please note that:

- The *product* variable is initialized as an empty object {};
- The "retrieveProduto()" method is called after the user clicks a button. It then makes an API call and, after the promise resolves, updates the *product* variable.
- I am using axios to make the http request, and it returns a *response* object, where *response.data* is the content of the returned object.

The console.log(this.product) results in

> {id: 1, name: "Lemon cake", description: "Traditional lemon cake", pic_url: "", category_id: 1, …}

which is exactly the expected output. However, upon calling {{ product }} in the view, the template is not updated in any way, and gets stuck forever in {}.

I have also tested if two-way databinding is working, and the answer is yes. Actually, everything is working perfectly apart from this. Am I doing something wrong? Should I expect that the template is not updated after retrieving an object from a promise?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

- The part of the template in which I call the variable is just a  {{product}} for testing purposes.
- The reason why I am calling *self* is that I was using *this.product* in my first attempts. I have seen this [solution elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45282704/3999482) and changed it so I could give it a shot. Since it didn't work, I am changing it back to *this*
- Printing *console.log(this)* returns the complete Vue object, and it has the *product* property set correctly, but still not reflecting in the template.

Comment: Where do you set the `data.product` in this code ? I dont see it and give us the part of the template that renders !!

Comment: You don't actually ever declare `self`.

Comment: @WilomGfx I have edited the post to add some info. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be some issues with scoping.
Try this:

```
  retrieveProduct(id) {
    axios.get('/product/' + id).then(response => {
      this.product = response.data;
    });
  }
```

And then use `vue-devtools` to check if the data is properly changed.

Comment: It worked!! Apparently it has to do with the old javascript notation. Using .then(response => { did the trick. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped! haha

Answer (score 2):

You could be running into issues with `self`, whether due to lack of declaration or scoping issues. Try the following instead:

```
retrieveProduct(id) {
    var this_vue_instance = this;
    axios.get('/product/'+id).then(function (response) {
        this_vue_instance.product = response.data;
        console.log(this_vue_instance.product);
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I had previously tried it with *this*. Please take a look at the edits.

Comment: @Cortifero were you sure to use the `var this_vue_instance` line? `this` will not probably not refer to the Vue instance if you're within the `axios.get()` scope.

Comment: Yes, I have changed my code to exactly what you suggested. Makes perfect sense, but it doesn't work. console.log(this_vue_instance) also shows the product property. Not reflecting changes in the template, though